# css inline block layout issue

Tags: css

I'm having problem with the `display:inline-block` CSS property. Imagine we have some divs and we assign a class called box to them here is the code:

```
.box{
    border:5px gray solid;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Now if we have some divs next to each other if the content of divs are not empty we don't have problem but of some divs were empty we will have some unexpected results. Why?

I have taken images:

[This is when divs are full](http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-08/09287408744405122569.png)
[image]

[This is when some divs are empty](http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-08/19049433258505206769.png)
[image]

Even I added some `nbsp;` but the result turned into:

[image]

Comment: Show us some code what have you tried

Comment: No, we won't imagine. Instead, show us the actual markup. Further, don't insult StackOverflow when you come to StackOverflow for help; it's not very smart of you.

Comment: Sounds like a 'vertical-align:top' issue.

Comment: I think stackoverflow should rethink about its hard rules ......

Comment: @UltraDEVV I think you need to [spend some time learning the rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you criticize them, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `display:inline-block` in its default setting, the vertical alignment of the div is set to `baseline`. You can change this to `baseline`, `top`, `middle` or `bottom` (the most commonly used values).

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

To solve your issue add this to the css:

```
    vertical-align:top;
```

So you've got

```
.box{
   border:5px gray solid;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the `vertical-align:top` rule on your divs. The default vertical alignment for inline elements is baseline, which is what you're seeing.